# Crop square photo with picker.allowsEditing = true in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm currently coding a social app which permits to share pictures. The user has the possibility to share pictures from his/her library.

```
func selectImg() {
      let picker = UIImagePickerController()
      picker.delegate = self
      picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
      picker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
      picker.allowsEditing = true
      present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then, the user has to crop the picture in order to having a square version of it. For that, I wrote `picker.allowsEditing = true`, but the problem is that the cropped zone is not seems to be improper, here is what is looks like:

[image]

As you can see with this square picture, the cropping zone is displaced and I really don't know why. I tried to check if users had the same problem, but no result.

Comment: It's hard to say from the little information you're giving. You need to give more information about the view controller that's presenting the picker and how it's set up. I would suggest adding code to put a border around the parent view controller's view to see if IT is displaced (`self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1`.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was due to the status bar